# Can't install openssh using APT, GDebi

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh, apt

I am trying to install `openssh-server` on my home PC for remote access. `openssh-client` v1:7.4p1-10 is already installed, so need to install the same server version (or update the client). I am running the Mate variant of Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty).

The methods I have tried, and the errors which they gave, are below.

- **Doing `apt install openssh-server`**

  `E:Package 'openssh-server' has no installation candidate`
- **Downloading the `.deb` file from the Ubuntu repo and installing using `GDebi`**

  7.4p1 is not available on the Ubuntu repo.

  - Attempting to install a later version gives `Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libc6 (>= 2.26)` (zesty uses debian stretch, which uses libc6 v2.24-11)
  - Attempting to install an earlier version of `openssh-server` gives `Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: openssh-client (=1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4)`
  - Attempting to install an earlier version of `openssh-client` (in order to satisfy the previous dependency) gives `Error: A later version is already installed`
- **Downloading the `.deb` file from the Debian repo and installing using `GDebi`**

  - Attempting to install `openssh-server` gives `Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: openssh-client (=1.74p1-10+deb9u2)`
  - Attempting to install `openssh-client` (to fix the previous issue) gives `Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libssl1.0.2 (>=1.0.2d)`
  - Attempting to install `libssl1.0.2` (to fix the fix) (using APT) gives `E: Unable to locate package libssl1.0.2`

Although the issue did not arise until I attempted to install this particular package, it seems that the issue is with `apt` in some way. As such it may be notable that the only mention of `openssh-server` in the entire `apt` cache is as a suggestion of `rsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.04 is EOL : [Ubuntu release end of life](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)

> When an Ubuntu release reaches its “end of life” it receives no further maintenance updates, including critical security upgrades. We highly recommend that you upgrade to a recent version of Ubuntu at this point

To keep using Ubuntu 17.04, edit your `sources.list` as follows ( [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Past the lines:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Update your system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Comment: Thank you! I assumed I had an LTS version because I have always installed LTS for other people, but apparently not... I will probably update my distro rather than change my sources. (I've also been waiting for an excuse to switch from MateDE to KDE.)